# PHP online exam from database

Tags: php, mysql

Here i wish to make a online exam portal based on subject. Corresponding staffs assigned for each subject will add the questions and options in database. Each option have a radiobutton. I display the page in using a while loop. The radio button for the all options for each question have same name. so i can't select the answers one by one. If i checked a answer for a question, then the answer of other will be unchecked. I don't know what to do.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table width="200" border="1">
        <?php
        while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($vtb)) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="images/qe.png" width="19" height="17"/><b><font size=""><?php echo $r[2] ?></font></b></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input name="a1" type="radio" value="" /><?php echo $r[3] ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input name="a1" type="radio" value="" /><?php echo $r[4] ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input name="a1" type="radio" value="" /><?php echo $r[5] ?></td></tr>
            <tr> <td><input name="a1" type="radio" value="" /><?php echo $r[6] ?></td>
            </tr>

            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: After reading your post, I don't know what you're asking. Please clarify.

Comment: there are soo many things wrong with your code/approach. You are using an outdated api, form tag isn't closed, using `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`

Comment: You are also open to injection attacks by inserting a `$_REQUEST` var directly into the request string without verification/proper binding

Comment: Akhila, Mysql_ is deprecated. You should really be using MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: ok thanku.. my problem is i put the radio buttons in while loop and i have  10 questions for each subject. The radio button for each question is same.

Comment: you want to check more then one radiobutton? use cheboxes!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$viewid=$_REQUEST['sid'];

$vtb=mysqli_query($link,"select *from tblexam where sid='$viewid'");
//$r=mysql_fetch_array($vtb);
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <table width="200" border="1">
        <?php
        while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($vtb, MYSQLI_NUM))
        {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="images/qe.png" width="19" height="17"/><b><font size=""><?php echo $r[2] ?></font></b></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input name="a<?php echo $r[0] ?>" type="radio" value="1" /><?php echo $r[3] ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input name="a<?php echo $r[0] ?>" type="radio" value="2" /><?php echo $r[4] ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input name="a<?php echo $r[0] ?>" type="radio" value="3" /><?php echo $r[5] ?></td></tr>
            <tr> <td><input name="a<?php echo $r[0] ?>" type="radio" value="4" /><?php echo $r[6] ?></td>
            </tr>

            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

I assume `$r[0]` is your question_id. 
change it to your `question_id` location if it isn't.

**Please be aware** mysql_ is now deprecated and you should either be using MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: please do not give answers using the deprecated `mysql_*`. it doesn't help the OP. You are encouraging bad practices.

Comment: in case there is no `question_id` or it's easier for the results processing, a simple var that increments at each while loop turn can do instead of `$r[0]`

Comment: Thanku v much Wils.. Actually it's not a live project. that'y i used mysql instead of mysqli..anyway thanku all

Comment: one more doubt. If we want to get the clicked value in a php variable, Is this the correct method? $a1=$_POST['al'.$r[0]];

Comment: $a1=$_POST['a'.$r[0]];